# for-loop construction start in a c++ program

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a problem in the for-construction, I don't know why my counting starts from 0 but you can't write on it(you can write starting with Register 1).I've marked in the code where is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
std::string day, date;
int registerCount;

std::cout << "INPUT DATA"
          << std::endl << std::endl
          << "Enter the day in which you want to perform the register: "
          << std::endl;
std::cin >> day;
std::cout << "DATE:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> date;
std::cout << "Enter the number of registers you wanna perfom for the day "
          << day << ":" << std::endl;
std::cin >> registerCount;

std::vector<std::string> registers(registerCount);
for (int i = 0; i < registerCount; ++i)     **here is the problem**
{
    std::cout << "Register " << i << ":" << std::endl;       **it starts from 0 but you can't write on Register 0**
    std::getline(std::cin, registers[i]);
}

std::cout << "The data for the day of " << day << " are the following: "
          << std::endl;

std::cout << "DATE: " << date << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < registerCount; ++i)
    std::cout << registers[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: std::cout << "Register " << i + 1 << ":" << std::endl; ???

Comment: it doesn't work i've tried if i put i+1 it will start from 1 and will be able to write on register 2

Comment: I don't get your question, in the loop you initialize the variable in 0...

Comment: What is your actual problem? Your absence of punctuation makes it hard to follow.

Comment: The problem is that i can't write on 0 ! I can write just starting from Register 1

Comment: Try this:- for (int i = 1; i < registerCount; ++i)

Comment: The arrays start in index 0, so, why you can't write in that index?

Comment: Do you mean you aren't allowed to write to `0`? Then start the loop at `1`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Header - `#include<limits>`

after your

`std::cin >> registerCount;`

to "eat up" the trailing newline coming from previous `std::cin` which is cause of skipping of the first input

Comment: can you write the personalized version for my program please ? just cin.ignore function

Comment: @CokeThe See [here](http://ideone.com/REJqV0)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < registerCount; ++i)
```

You're defining i as starting at 0 here. Very simply, all you need to do is change the "i = 0" to "i = 1".

The way you're assigning to that vector looks a little bit wrong too. I think you need to use push_back() on the vector in that syntax, but I'm not too familiar with all the different operators for vector.